# How do I send an html text form to javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have an html form on my page that I want to send to a javascript function.  How do I send values to that function/activate it  so the function runs?

```
<form  method="post" action="WHAT GOES HERE?">
<input type = "textarea" name = "link" placeholder="Submit a Link" style="color:black;max-width:133px;"></input>
<input type = "hidden" name = "ref" value="yes"></input>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="submit();">Submit</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't "send" the form anywhere. Javascript can read the form values at any time. You usually attach an `onsubmit` event to the form or an `onclick` event to the submit button, then when that happens you use Javascript to read in the form values.

For example, you can read the value of your "ref" input by first giving it an id...

```
<input id="ref" name="ref" ...
```

Then read it with Javascript like so,

```
document.getElementById('ref').value
```

It's up to you what you do with that value.

Also, your HTML is a bit off. Inputs should be self closing (`<input/>`) and to create a textarea you're supposed to use `<textarea></textarea>`.

Edit: If you just wanted a 1-line textbox, it should be `<input type="text" ...` not textarea. The reason it works is because the default for an `input` happens to be `text`.

Comment: DING DING DING! Awesome! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the forms `onsubmit` event

```
<form  method="post" action="" onsubmit="validateForm()">
<input type = "textarea" name = "link" placeholder="Submit a Link" style="color:black;max-width:133px;"></input>
<input type = "hidden" name = "ref" value="yes"></input>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="submit();">Submit</a>
```

Comment: Is validateForm a builtin function?

Comment: also, how do you then retrieve the values for link and ref?

Comment: you'll have to set up your own javascript function in this case "validateForm". You can then select the inputs and validate as needed

Comment: oh so validateForm is my javascript function name, within that function, how do I access the link value? and the "ref" value?

Comment: you can use a jQuery selector on the input's name. something like this here: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>


<script type="text/javascript">
function getValue(){
var textValue=document.getElementById("textId").value;
alert(textValue);
}
</script>


</head>
<body>
<form  method="post" >
<input type = "textarea" id="textId" name = "link" placeholder="Submit a Link"       style="color:black;max-width:133px;"></input>
<input type = "hidden" name = "ref" value="yes"></input>
<a href="#" onclick="getValue();">Submit</a> 
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

1.create id for textarea. **id="textId"**

2.Fetch the value of textarea using the id created in the javascript using the method 
**document.getElementById("textId").value;**

Comment: You don't need `javascript:` in `onXXX` attributes; that's only needed in `href`.